# How do I select Process ID (PID) in powershell Get-Counter script?

Tags: powershell

This script is giving me the CPU for each node process. Which is great. But I need to know the PID for each process so that I can match specific process to CPU usage.

```
$ProcessName = "node"

$CpuCores = (Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem).NumberOfLogicalProcessors
$Samples = (Get-Counter "\Process($Processname*)\% Processor Time").CounterSamples
$Samples | Select InstanceName,@{Name="CPU %";Expression={[Decimal]::Round(($_.CookedValue / $CpuCores), 4)}}
```

I've searched everywhere I can think. I've tried PID, ID, ProcessID, InstanceID and many other variants.

Seems like it should be simple?

Comment: you will need to get that with `Get-Process`. you  can use the `$ProcessName` to cross reference the two data sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dot referencing specific properties and that's all you'll get back. Thus, you cannot ask for what is not supplied.

```
# Using variable squeezing to output results to the screen while assigning results to the variable.

($ProcessName = "dllhost")
($CpuCores = (Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem).NumberOfLogicalProcessors)
($Samples = (Get-Counter "\Process($Processname*)\% Processor Time").CounterSamples)
($Samples | Select InstanceName,@{Name="CPU %";Expression={[Decimal]::Round(($_.CookedValue / $CpuCores), 4)}})

# Results
<#
dllhost
8

Path                                       InstanceName CookedValue
----                                       ------------ -----------
\\lab01\process(dllhost#2)\% processor time dllhost                0
\\lab01\process(dllhost#1)\% processor time dllhost                0
\\lab01\process(dllhost)\% processor time   dllhost                0
                                           dllhost                 
                                           dllhost                 
                                           dllhost                 
#>

Get-Process -Name 'dllhost'

# Results
<#
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
    120       7     1580       6760       0.11   8612   2 dllhost    
    200      17     3620      11332       0.09  14176   0 dllhost    
    229      16     3984      12216       0.36  15940   2 dllhost
#>

Get-Counter -Counter "\Process($Processname*)\% Processor Time"

# Results
<#
Timestamp                 CounterSamples
---------                 --------------
23-Nov-19 17:52:10        \\lab01\process(dllhost#2)\% processor time :
                          3.11758575755139                            

                          \\lab01\process(dllhost#1)\% processor time :
                          0             

                          \\lab01\process(dllhost)\% processor time :  
                          0
#>
```

So, you need to combine the above for a single result. There are differ ways to do this of course, For example:

```
Clear-Host
Get-Process -Name 'WUDFHost' | 
ForEach {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'ProcessName' = $PSItem.ProcessName
        'ProcessId' = $PSItem.Id
        'Path' = $PSItem.Path
        'Cookedvalue'  = ((Get-Counter -Counter "\Process($($PSItem.Name))\% Processor Time").CounterSamples).CookedValue
    } 
}

# Results
<#
ProcessName ProcessId Path                                  Cookedvalue
----------- --------- ----                                  -----------
WUDFHost         1100 C:\Windows\System32\WUDFHost.exe 21.8216373679803
WUDFHost         4020 C:\Windows\System32\WUDFHost.exe 6.23866621508705
WUDFHost         4644 C:\Windows\System32\WUDFHost.exe 9.36077443109706
WUDFHost        10280 C:\Windows\System32\WUDFHost.exe 3.11837874640775
#>
```